# Picture VS Byte Array?

Tags: android, storage, webclient

I have pictures to send to a server from an android device.
I'm trying to find out which is perhaps better as a storage option.

I'm struggling to see which format will use less storage space on the device and server. I am already sending data(text) from Db's over to server.

So wondering if it's best to put the pictures as byte arrays into db (stored and sent) seeing as I have Db's already
OR
Keep the pic's out of db and send separate.

Comment: send separate so you can resend from the point it lost connection to server if you got unstable connection. or if your connection is stable, you can just gzip them

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you

```
public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {

 File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);


 WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
 DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

 return ( data.getData() );
}
```